# Is there any stem cell or biogel method that exist for muscle and tendon lengthening?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles, tendons

Is there any stem cell or biogel method that exist for muscle and tendon lengthening?

It is known that height surgery is limit to six inches with two surgeries and three inches each, it is also true that there is limit because the muscle and tendons could stretch no more. Is there some research about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In doing search into muscle stem cells, I found some articles which discuss roles of [satellite stem cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosatellite_cell) and non satellite cells  involved in muscle regeneration: ([Yin, Price and Rudnicki, 2013](http://physrev.physiology.org/content/93/1/23.short),[Seale and Rudnicki, 2000](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012160699995659), and [Mitchell et al, 2010](http://www.nature.com/ncb/journal/v12/n3/full/ncb2025.html)).

Other articles, that I found discussed the splicing of [insulin-like growth factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin-like_growth_factor) (IGF-1) into the satellite stem cells rodent muscles and the subsequent expression of the gene were studied to understand how is plays a role in muscle repair ([Hill and Goldspink, 2003](http://jp.physoc.org/content/549/2/409.short), [Musaro et al, 2004](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC337031/)). Another study looked at how [transforming growth factor-β](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transforming_growth_factor_beta) (TGF-β) and its interaction in the [Notch signaling pathway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notch_signaling_pathway) play a role in smooth muscle repair [(Kurpiinski et al, 2010)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/stem.319/full)( [Review Articles by Péault et al, 2007](http://www.nature.com/mt/journal/v15/n5/full/6300145a.html)  and [Seagers and Lee, 2008](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v451/n7181/full/nature06800.html) )

As for current methods on the application of stem cells to myogeneration or myoregeneration, there are a few papers that I found but, it seems like we are still too far away from anything that is medically feasible ([Zhu et al, 2014](http://www.nature.com/cr/journal/v24/n10/full/cr201491a.html), [Milner and Cameron, 2013](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23224711))

Hopefully that answered your question or at least put you on the right track in your research.

**EDIT**: I found some papers on tendon repair and growth, but the conclusions are the same, in that there is much more research and technology improvements to be done ([Awad et al, 2007](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/ten.1999.5.267) and [Breidenbach et al, 2014](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25266738))

Answer (score 4):

Limb lengthening surgery is usually used to treat sequelae caused by bone disease, trauma, pygmyism or inflammation. I personally do not recommend to use surgical methods to increase height. Typically Limb Lengthening requires Achilles pre-lengthening surgery and a lot of postoperative rehabilitation. Moreover, Limb lengthening surgery may cause pain, infection, muscle atrophy, joint stiffness and delayed bone healing. There's a lot of related research cause this study is timely for some patients.

ALDEGHERI, R., RENZI-BRIVIO, L., & AGOSTINI, S. (1989). The callotasis method of limb lengthening. Clinical Orthopaedics and Related Research, 241, 137-145.

De Bastiani, G., Aldegheri, R., Renzi-Brivio, L., & Trivella, G. (1987). Limb lengthening by callus distraction (callotasis). Journal of Pediatric Orthopaedics, 7(2), 129-134.

Paley, D. (1988). Current techniques of limb lengthening. Journal of Pediatric Orthopaedics, 8(1), 73-92.

Paley, D. (1990). Problems, obstacles, and complications of limb lengthening by the ilizarov technique. Clinical Orthopaedics and Related Research, 250, 81-104.

Szoke, G., Lee, S. H., Simpson, A. H., & Prescott, J. (2005). Response of the tendon during limb lengthening. The Journal of Bone and Joint Surgery.British Volume, 87(4), 583-587.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that just a Russian researcher named Dr Alexander Teplyashin has made any progress into using stem cells for LL (Limb lengthening). Conventional way to go about it would always be surgeries which are detailed in Wikipedia ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limb_lengthening_methods)). This is a relatively new development, so I could not find any relative publications to support the claim of this particular researcher. There is however a website detailing the news in English, most others being in Russian ([reference](http://www.naturalheightgrowth.com/2014/05/31/believe-alexander-teplyashin-got-stem-cell-technique-successfully-work/)) Here are a few publications of his ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Tepliashin%20AS%5BAuthor%5D&cauthor=true&cauthor_uid=17918338)). There are already lengthening methods available which is a combination of both surgery and stem cells ([reference](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/health/healthnews/8033218/Stem-cells-used-to-save-womans-leg.html)). As far as there is some credible proof, I would take the claims of that Russian researcher with a pinch of salt.

Comment: I upvoted it, however it is bone lengthening, not the muscle and tendon lengthening i asked